# Jquery loading dynamic page

Tags: javascript, jquery

It works when i click the button 2 times. Why?

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#new_pr").click(function(){
        $("#start_pr").load('parts/new-project.html')
            .slideToggle({height:'toggle'});
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<a id="new_pr">New Project</a>
<div id="start_pr"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V7u6v/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#new_pr").click(function(){
    $("#start_pr").hide(0);       
        $("#start_pr").load('http://echo.jsontest.com/uid/12345/value/nuno_bettencourt', function () {
                      $("#start_pr").show(200);
                })     
    });
});
```

Comment: can you setup jsfiddle?

Comment: hey, did you insert above in `document.ready`. don't miss that. i update my answer

Comment: can you setup jsFiddle?

Comment: I have fixed it, sorry it was my little mistake. It worked now

Comment: Is that working after putting slideToggle into complete function?

Comment: First time did not work, I checked script and found that after coping your script I mistakenly deleted `});` at the end, due this case script did not work. Now works,but when I click the button firstly is loaded `#start_pr`, then is slided up. It should be slided down. I will create fiddle now

Comment: @user10, thank you. I have one question more. in my `#start_pr` has a couple of sql query. Due this case I want use ajax reguest. So, query is worked efter clicking `new_pr`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: i don't understand. sql query on what language. do you mean HTML5 sql queries?

Comment: what do you expect in that case? do you want to run your query and then need to display your text in HTML?

Comment: Okay, let me explain. I should write a couple of sql query inside `start_pr`. And I want my php page sends sql reguests when I start clicking the button. After clicking is writed: Please wait, loading ... after a few seconds is opened `start_pr`  like yu have done it for me. You can see it on Facebook, when user wants to see likes list... So, php page will not send sql queries untill clicking the button

Comment: sorry. i don't really understand. I think you should look `$.ajax` in jquery and `writing rest based services` in php.

Comment: I have already found it :) http://8raystech.com/2011/06/28/how-to-dynamic-content-in-a-jquery-ui-dialog-by-loading-a-url-via-ajax